# Unable to get docker swarm mode working with nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I'm trying to get a basic nodeJs and postgres system up and running but for some reason the node container keeps receiving a SIGTERM signal and shutting down only to be started back up due to the restart policy and then shutdown again. The cycle goes on and on.

What am I missing here? I ran the same code in non-swarm mode and it worked fine, the container was healthy and stayed up. One more thing I did notice during swarm mode is that inspite of asking docker to keep 1 replica, the `docker stack services service_name` always returns 0/1 replicas

Posting my `dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file here

```
# BASE stage
FROM node:14-alpine as base
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --prod

FROM node:14-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV development
ENV VERSION V1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
COPY src src/
# Other copy commands
COPY --from=base /usr/src/app/node_modules /usr/src/app/node_modules

# check every 5s to ensure this service returns HTTP 200
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s --start-period=10s --retries=3 \ 
    CMD curl -fs http://localhost/health

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "src/index.js" ]
```

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api:
    image: demo/hobby:v1
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 5
        window: 120s
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 20s
        order: start-first
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 1s
        failure_action: rollback
        order: start-first
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - target: 9200
        published: 80
        mode: host
    networks:
      - verse

  postgres:
    image: "postgres:12.3-alpine"
    container_name: "test-db-dev"
    networks:
      - verse
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: "unless-stopped"

networks:
  verse:
    driver: overlay
    external: false
```

Comment: Are you deploying with `docker stack deploy`? Is your container being SIGTERMed every 30 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your container is being killed every 30 seconds. If this is true, then this is the cause:

The `HEALTHCHECK` is trying to curl http://localhost/health (defaults to port 80).
Although you expose the app to the host on port `80`, the `HEALTHCHECK` is performed from the container perspective, where no service is listening on that port.

Assuming that your node app is listening on port 9200 and that a `GET` performed on `/health` returns status `200`, the `Dockerfile` should be built like this:

```
[...]

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --timeout=3s --start-period=10s --retries=3 \ 
   CMD curl -fs http://localhost:9200/health

[...]
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Also a quick question here, what was the calculation to get the 30 seconds because that seemed pretty spot on.